# Getting Cake PHP to output a HTML submit button with a given class name

Tags: cakephp

I can get Cake to output a submit button using the following PHP:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

which outputs this HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

but I want to use a specific input class to get the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="some class">
```

is this possible?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit',true), array('class'=>'some class')); 
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Which is documented [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1431/submit).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => __('Submit', true), 'class' => 'some class')); ?>
```

Comment: Add a second `true` parameter to your `__()`, to return the value instead of *echoing* it.